# Convert Sub-query into Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, doctrine

I am trying to convert below query via Joins,

```
SELECT DISTINCT req.*
FROM request req
WHERE (req.user_id IN (
            SELECT id from user where id in (SELECT user_id FROM team_member team WHERE team.team_id IN ('344', '723')) and user.active = 1
)
OR req.user_id IN (
  SELECT id from user where id in (SELECT approved_employee_id from approver where approver_id = '269') and user.active = 1
))
   AND req.status = 'pending';
```

returns 124 records.

I have wrote below query via joins but doesn't work,

```
SELECT DISTINCT req.*
FROM request req
  LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = req.user_id AND u.active = 1
  LEFT JOIN team_member team ON team.user_id = u.id AND team.team_id IN ('344', '723')
  LEFT JOIN approver app ON app.approver_id = u.id AND app.approver_id = '269'
AND req.status = 'pending';
```

returns more than 500 records.

two issue with this joins, it includes those requests too where status is not pending.

Below is the schema

I have below tables

```
tbl_approver = 
id, 
approver_id (FK tbl_user), 
approver_team_id (FK tbl_team), 
approved_employee_id (FK tbl_user)

tbl_team_mambers = 
id, 
team_id (FK), 
user_id (FK)

tble_user = 
id, 
email, 
username
active


tbl_request = 
id, 
user_id, 
status
```

- Teams Members : A user is a member of multiple teams.
- Approver :

  - For each team there is an approver, who is also the member of that team.
  - there can be direct approver of an employee regardless of team.
- request : inventory requests by the user

> Note : as an approver, i can be member of many teams but only approver
>   of some team. or some employee too.

Query wanted : as an approver i want all request of my teams whom i am approver.

Comment: It would help if you included your schema, sample data, output and expected output.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library and has nothing to do with mysql/sql...try to tag questions  appropriately

Comment: @shmosel see the updated question now.

Comment: remove LEFT keyword and tell how many data it return

Answer (score 1):

For correct results of `join`'s you need to any joined "table" return only one row for user_id. And do not use `left` if needed only rows existing in all tables.

```
SELECT req.*
  FROM request req
  JOIN user ON user.id=req.user_id
  JOIN (
        SELECT distinct approved_employee_id as user_id from approver where approver_id = '269'
         UNION
        SELECT distinct user_id FROM team_member team WHERE team.team_id IN ('344', '723')
       ) A ON req.user_id=A.user_id
 where user.active = 1
   AND req.status = 'pending';
```

Or, if needed only "real table":

```
SELECT DISTINCT req.*
  FROM request req
  JOIN user u ON u.id = req.user_id AND u.active = 1
  LEFT JOIN team_member team ON team.user_id = u.id AND team.team_id IN ('344', '723')
  LEFT JOIN approver app  ON app.approver_id = u.id AND app.approver_id = '269'
 WHERE req.status = 'pending'
   AND (team.user_id is not null OR app.approver_id is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch the `LEFT JOIN` syntax, here's the [visual expression of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

```
SELECT DISTINCT req.*
FROM request req
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = req.user_id AND u.active = 1
...
```

This will select all distinct records from `request`, and `JOIN` them to user. The `join_condition` after `ON` will only affect the join relation.

> If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table.

[Join syntax from Mysql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

If you really want to use `LEFT JOIN` to filter all record from `request`, consider moving the `condition_expr` to `WHERE`

```
SELECT DISTINCT req.*
FROM request req
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = req.user_id
...
WHERE u.active = 1
AND ...
```

If you only need `request` that satisfies the join condition to user, you should consider use `Join` rather than `LEFT JOIN`.